# Inserting Data from one table into another table but in a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, sql-insert

I have two databases that contain all the same tables. So i am trying to copy data from one table in one database to the same table in the other database.

I am getting this error 'There is already an object named 'PayComponents' in the database.'

Not sure of another way to achieve what i want

```
SELECT * INTO [PSD2394].DBO.PayComponents
FROM [PSD1346].DBO.PayComponents
WHERE PCompID != 1 AND PCompID != 2
```

Expected Result - All records from DB - PSD1346 except where the PCompID = 1 and 2 are inserted into the PayComponents table in DB - PSD2394

Comment: Don't use `SELECT ...INTO` use `INSERT INTO...SELECT ...FROM` syntax. `SELECT...INTO` syntax will try to create the object and if it already exists error (as have happened here). `INSERT INTO...` syntax inserts data into an existing object,

Comment: @Mark . . . Drop the table before re-creating it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. Sorry dont think this is a wise move to do that. this table already exists with data in it, if i was to drop the table that could have negative effects. I am just trying to insert data into that table. is there no other way?

Comment: @Larnu i am now getting this error... An explicit value for the identity column in table 'PSD2394.DBO.PayComponents' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Comment: You need to tell it what fields to insert, and not include the identity column. See my answer for an example

Comment: @GuidoG Ok gonna give it a go here. Thanks for the answer. ill let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT INTO will create a new table each time, if that is what you want then you need to drop that table first.

To append in an existing table, you need to use the INSERT INTO SELECT for that, like this example

```
INSERT * INTO [PSD2394].DBO.PayComponents (column names...)
SELECT pc.column names...
FROM   [PSD1346].DBO.PayComponents pc
WHERE  pc.PCompID != 1 
AND    pc.PCompID != 2
```

If the primary key of `[PSD2394].DBO.PayComponents` is an identity field, you cannot copy it, because the database will not allow you to write an own value in an identity field.
In case you really need that, try this

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [PSD2394].DBO.PayComponents ON

do the insert statement here...

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [PSD2394].DBO.PayComponents OFF
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The SET IDENTITY_INSERT worked a treat. This has saved so much manual inputting of data. Thanks again much appreciated.